# How can I generate a previous value table by combining fields from SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have some data in a SQL Server database.

```
Location   PayID    Year
------------------------
Loc1        100     2010
Loc1        100     2011
Loc1        101     2012
Loc2        200     2010
Loc2        201     2011
Loc2        202     2012
```

And I am trying to write a query in SQL Server that will give me a table with two columns that I can search on to find out what the previous `PayID` for a particular Location. So the output would be.

```
PayID   PrevID
-----------------
101     100
202     201
201     200
```

It only needs an entry when the previous year ID is different from the current year and I will query it recursively if I don't have the right match when a user goes back more than one year so It will pull each previous ID based on the one that was just pulled until it finds a PayID and Year matching the first table.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. I'll be attentively searching and will post a solution if I can find it.

Comment: Where does the 202-201 mapping come from?

Comment: Sorry about that, 202 should have been Loc2 as well.  Loc3 was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done pretty easily with a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
  select Location, PayID, PayID as PrevID, Year from payhistory
  union all
  select p.Location, p.PayID, cte.PayID as PrevID, p.Year
  from payhistory p
  join cte on cte.Location = p.Location and cte.Year + 1 = p.Year
)
select distinct Location, PayID, PrevID
from cte
where PayID <> PrevID;
```

Here's the results I get:

```
| LOCATION | PAYID | PREVID |
|----------|-------|--------|
|     Loc1 |   101 |    100 |
|     Loc2 |   201 |    200 |
|     Loc2 |   202 |    201 |
```

Demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0ac0/4

Comment: That looks like a great solution but my data is all varchar because that's how I get it.  I apologize for not saying that. Is there any way to adapt it?

Comment: It shouldn't matter if `Location` and `PayID` are varchar.  If the years are also strings, then it should be a simple matter of casting: `CAST(cte.YEAR as INTEGER) + 1 = CAST(P.YEAR as INTEGER)`.

Comment: @mellamokb - Is there a way to do this without CTE which is - as fast as cte and "simple" ? I made a query, but its not going to work in all cases - gaps in payId, non-consecutive payIds etc.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't see a version specified, so I'd use LAG in 2012. You can filter the results if you want less info. You could replace LAG(PayID,1,NULL) with LAG(PayID,1,PayID) to alter the behavior of the first payid.

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Location VARCHAR(4),   PayID INT,    Year INT)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('Loc1',100,2010)
,('Loc1',100,2011)
,('Loc1',101,2012)
,('Loc2',200,2010)
,('Loc2',201,2011)
,('Loc2',202,2012)

SELECT Location 
      ,PayID
      ,LAG(PayID,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY Year ASC) PrevID
  FROM @tbl
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e0ac0/2

Answer (score 0):

**Key assumption -** This query will work only if the PayIds for each location are consecutive numbers.

```
select distinct l1.payId as PayId, 
l2.payId as PrevId
from locs as l1
inner join locs as l2
on l1.location = l2.location
and l1.payid = (l2.payid + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Following solution is non-recursive and it might offer a better performance:

```
DECLARE @Payment TABLE (
    ID          INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    Location    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    PayID       INT NOT NULL,
    [Year]      SMALLINT NOT NULL
);
INSERT @Payment
SELECT 'Loc1', 100, 2010
UNION ALL SELECT 'Loc1', 100, 2011
UNION ALL SELECT 'Loc1', 101, 2012
UNION ALL SELECT 'Loc2', 200, 2010
UNION ALL SELECT 'Loc2', 201, 2011
UNION ALL SELECT 'Loc2', 202, 2012


SELECT  z.Location, z.GroupID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN z.RowType = 1 THEN z.[Year] END)  AS CurrentYear,
        MAX(CASE WHEN z.RowType = 0 THEN z.[Year] END)  AS PreviousYear,
        MAX(CASE WHEN z.RowType = 1 THEN z.[PayID] END) AS CurrentPayID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN z.RowType = 0 THEN z.[PayID] END) AS PreviousPayID
FROM
(
    SELECT  y.PayID, y.[Location], y.[Year],
            -- It "groups" rows two by two: current row and previous row will have the same GroupID
            (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY y.Location ORDER BY y.RowNum + n.Num ASC) + 1) / 2 AS GroupID,
            -- RowType: 1=Current row, 0=Previous row
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY y.Location ORDER BY y.RowNum + n.Num ASC) % 2 AS RowType 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT  x.Location, x.[Year], x.PayID, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.Location ORDER BY x.[Year] DESC) RowNum
        FROM    @Payment x
    ) y
    -- For every location, it duplicates every row except the last one
    INNER JOIN (VALUES (1), (2)) n(Num) ON y.RowNum = 1 AND n.Num = 1 OR y.RowNum > 1 
) z
GROUP BY z.Location, z.GroupID
HAVING  MAX(CASE WHEN z.RowType = 1 THEN z.[Year] END) = MAX(CASE WHEN z.RowType = 0 THEN z.[Year] END) + 1
AND     MAX(CASE WHEN z.RowType = 1 THEN z.[PayID] END) <> MAX(CASE WHEN z.RowType = 0 THEN z.[PayID] END)
ORDER BY z.Location;
```

Output:

```
Location  GroupID CurrentYear PreviousYear CurrentPayID PreviousPayID
--------- ------- ----------- ------------ ------------ -------------
Loc1      1       2012        2011         101          100
Loc2      1       2012        2011         202          201
Loc2      2       2011        2010         201          200
```